# How can i solve problem of playing video in django?

Tags: django-2.2

When i am writing the video tag in single html page with same video path then it works in browser and video is played.

But when i work with django video is not played.
Please help me out in this.

Comment: Welcome to the site. So that the community can help you, please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...
I gave an absolute path to check whether video is load or not?
But tha url which you have set for storing videos either media or static . You have to give that path only then django will load video on url.